# What's the correct way to use media queries to get perfect responsiveness for images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using Bootstrap, and I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="header-back one"></div>
```

Then I have `@media` queries that look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/320x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }    
}

@media(min-width: 375px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/375x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 425px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/425x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/768x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/1024x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1440px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/1440x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1441px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/2560x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }
}
```

The issue is that this isn't seamless.

For instance, this is how it looks on my 13" Macbook Pro:

[image]

Notice the grey background. That shouldn't be there. The entire middle block should be blue background.

The size of the div is 1200+ px, so some rule isn't working properly:

[image]

Am I using these media-queries correctly? Do I even need to be doing it like this? I just want a smooth experience across all devices at these breakpoints....how do I achieve that?

**Edit 1**

After rejigging the styles per Tha'er's suggestion below, this is what I did:

```
.landing-page .header-back.one {
  background: asset-url('landing/2560x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  // background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/320x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }

}

@media(max-width: 375px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/375x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }    
}

@media(max-width: 425px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/425x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/768x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1024px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/1024x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1440px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/1440x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
    // background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

This is what that produced, which is the largest image squished into the smallest viewport (which is not what I want):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1 way to achieve what you want is to use image as div background instead as using it inside the div. Adding an image inside the div isnt always going to give good results in all sizes, using the div background image method will give you good results in all screen sizes.

```
.div { background-image: url(image.jpg);
```

background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;

This should give you good results in all screen sizes which i guess is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How is this different than what I am doing now? Isn't this: `background: asset-url('landing/1440x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;` what you are suggesting?

Comment: Oh I missed that. The issue is that I want to use different images depending on the size of the screenport, so not the same image squished.

Comment: In all the media queries add background size cover.

Comment: It seems this works...while I am resizing it moves the background image. That's the intended behavior right?

Comment: Yep. Thats created from background size cover.

Comment: So are all of my `min-width` rules ok? Especially the last two....they feel a bit weird....but I am trying to have two different images for below 1440 and 1441+.

Comment: The thing with using an image as div background is that you dont really need that much media queries. Having that much media queries is not a good sign but well thats in theory, in specific cases its really needed. Its up to you now to check how things appear in screen sizes and where yoy can minimise code

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all `min-width` with `max-width` instead, example:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .landing-page .header-back.one {
     background: asset-url('landing/320x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Then what do I do of the largest one? Change that to `min-width`? What are the gotchas with this approach? I feel like I tried this before and I had some issues, but I am not able to remember/duplicate them right now.

Comment: Oh right....I was just able to replicate it. If I do this and set the min-width at the largest, when I resize the screen to smaller sizes it doesn't go to the smaller image I expect.

Comment: If you set all as `max-width` and remove the last media query and put its content (`.landing-page .header-back.one {
    background: asset-url('landing/1440x500-View-Anywhere.jpg') 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }`) above all media queries it should fix your problem

Comment: Nope....I am still seeing the largest background when I am at the smallest viewport. Aka this is how it looks: http://imgur.com/a/y6JrB

Comment: Did you put it before all media queries (at the top of the file)?

Comment: Ok, your problem will be that for example between 425px and 768px the 768px image will be shown, and it will be cropped. What I will suggest is reverting back to `min-width` again, but now using `background-position: center;` with a blue (same as the image's blue) background. This way you'll have the best behavior possible

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple slides, aka. `.header-back .two`, `.header-back .three`, etc. Not all backgrounds are blue. So I need something that works across any image type and all viewports.

Comment: You can put each one of these slides in a `div` that has a `width: 100%` and a `background-color` near the image. That way you can have multiple colors for your multiple slides

Comment: Nah....that's too much customization and rigidity. I need flexibility. I like Arber's suggestion of simply using `background-size: cover`.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but it might distort the image a little bit, but you can't have everything together ;)